# How to add custom field to checkout page according to product category and product quantity?

Tags: woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce project where different email packages are sold. On the checkout page, I want to create custom fields according to the products that the customer will buy. These fields should be different according to both the product and the quantity purchased. So when the customer buys different packages, they need to write emails in different custom fields. I think I can explain better in the image below.

[image]

The codes given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53885093/7836814) work very well, but it outputs as many custom fields as the product total, not separately.

Can you help me?

Comment: We expect from you to provide in your question your own real code attempt, even if it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the code that exactly meets my requirements. The code also includes saving the email custom fields to the order, making it display on the admin order page and sending it to the customer.

```
// Adding a custom field for the specified category quantity on the payment page
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field($checkout) {
    // Specific categories
    $allowed_categories = array('category-1', 'category-2', 'category-3');

    // Create an array to store quantity information based on category
    $category_counts = array();

    // Check the products in the cart
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get the product categories
        $product_categories = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');

        // If it belongs to specific categories, add the quantity
        if ($product_categories && is_array($product_categories)) {
            foreach ($product_categories as $category) {
                if (in_array($category->slug, $allowed_categories)) {
                    // Update the quantity for the specific category
                    if (!isset($category_counts[$category->slug])) {
                        $category_counts[$category->slug] = 0;
                    }

                    $category_counts[$category->slug] += $cart_item['quantity'];
                    break; // Exit the loop after finding the first match
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add titles and custom fields based on categories
    foreach ($category_counts as $category_slug => $count) {
        // Get the category name
        $category_name = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat')->name;

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            echo '<h3>Enter your desired ' . $i . '  email address for ' . ucfirst($category_name) . ' Package:</h3>';

            woocommerce_form_field($category_slug . '_cstm_email_' . $i, array(
                'type'        => 'email',
                'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                'placeholder' => __('Enter Email Address'),
                'required'    => true,
            ), $checkout->get_value($category_slug . '_cstm_email_' . $i));

            echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
        }
    }
}

// Save custom field values to the order
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_checkout_field');

function save_custom_checkout_field($order_id) {
    // Specific categories
    $allowed_categories = array('category-1', 'category-2', 'category-3');

    // Create an array to store quantity information based on category
    $category_counts = array();

    // Check the products in the cart
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

        // Get the product categories
        $product_categories = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');

        // If it belongs to specific categories, add the quantity
        if ($product_categories && is_array($product_categories)) {
            foreach ($product_categories as $category) {
                if (in_array($category->slug, $allowed_categories)) {
                    // Update the quantity for the specific category
                    if (!isset($category_counts[$category->slug])) {
                        $category_counts[$category->slug] = 0;
                    }

                    $category_counts[$category->slug] += $cart_item['quantity'];
                    break; // Exit the loop after finding the first match
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Save titles and custom fields based on categories to the order
    foreach ($category_counts as $category_slug => $count) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            $meta_key = $category_slug . '_cstm_email_' . $i;
            $meta_value = sanitize_email($_POST[$meta_key]);

            // Save the custom field value to the order
            if (!empty($meta_value)) {
                update_post_meta($order_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Display custom field values on the admin order page
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_custom_checkout_field_on_order_edit_pages', 10, 1);

function display_custom_checkout_field_on_order_edit_pages($order){
    // Specific categories
    $allowed_categories = array('category-1', 'category-2', 'category-3');

    // Create an array to store quantity information based on category
    $category_counts = array();

    // Check the products in the order
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

        // Get the product categories
        $product_categories = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');

        // If it belongs to specific categories, add the quantity
        if ($product_categories && is_array($product_categories)) {
            foreach ($product_categories as $category) {
                if (in_array($category->slug, $allowed_categories)) {
                    // Update the quantity for the specific category
                    if (!isset($category_counts[$category->slug])) {
                        $category_counts[$category->slug] = 0;
                    }

                    $category_counts[$category->slug] += $item->get_quantity();
                    break; // Exit the loop after finding the first match
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Display titles and custom fields based on categories on the admin order page
    foreach ($category_counts as $category_slug => $count) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            $meta_key = $category_slug . '_cstm_email_' . $i;
            $meta_value = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), $meta_key, true);

            // Display the custom field value on the admin order page
            if (!empty($meta_value)) {
                echo '<p><strong> ' . $i . ' Desired Email for ' . ucfirst($category_slug) . ' Package:</strong> ' . esc_html($meta_value) . '</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}

// Add custom fields to the order email
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'custom_checkout_field_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3);

function custom_checkout_field_email_order_meta_fields($fields, $sent_to_admin, $order) {
    // Specific categories
    $allowed_categories = array('category-1', 'category-2', 'category-3');

    // Create an array to store quantity information based on category
    $category_counts = array();

    // Check the products in the order
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

        // Get the product categories
        $product_categories = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');

        // If it belongs to specific categories, add the quantity
        if ($product_categories && is_array($product_categories)) {
            foreach ($product_categories as $category) {
                if (in_array($category->slug, $allowed_categories)) {
                    // Update the quantity for the specific category
                    if (!isset($category_counts[$category->slug])) {
                        $category_counts[$category->slug] = 0;
                    }

                    $category_counts[$category->slug] += $item->get_quantity();
                    break; // Exit the loop after finding the first match
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Add custom fields to the order email
    $i = 1; // Custom field counter
    foreach ($category_counts as $category_slug => $count) {
        $category_name = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat')->name;

        for ($j = 1; $j <= $count; $j++) {
            $meta_key = $category_slug . '_cstm_email_' . $j;
            $meta_value = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), $meta_key, true);

            // If there is a custom field value, add it to the email template
            if (!empty($meta_value)) {
                $fields['custom_fields_' . $i]['label'] = ' . $i . ' Desired Email for ' . ucfirst($category_slug) . ' Package:;
                $fields['custom_fields_' . $i]['value'] = $meta_value;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return $fields;
}
```